# what happens when vagrant box is removed with a machine still using it?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have around 15 vagrant machines. Those machines use CentOS and Ubuntu as their base boxes. I get following output when I run `vagrant box list`

`centos/7                      (virtualbox, 1705.01)
centos/7                      (virtualbox, 1706.02)
centos/7                      (virtualbox, 1707.01)
centos/7                      (virtualbox, 1708.01)
geerlingguy/centos7           (virtualbox, 1.2.3)
geerlingguy/ubuntu1604        (virtualbox, 1.1.6)
laravel/homestead             (virtualbox, 3.0.0)
puppetlabs/centos-7.2-64-nocm (virtualbox, 1.0.1)
ubuntu/precise64              (virtualbox, 20170427.0.0)
ubuntu/trusty64               (virtualbox, 20170615.0.0)
ubuntu/trusty64               (virtualbox, 20170619.0.0)
ubuntu/xenial64               (virtualbox, 20170802.0.0)
ubuntu/xenial64               (virtualbox, 20170815.1.0)
ubuntu/yakkety64              (virtualbox, 20170202.0.0)
ubuntu/zesty64                (virtualbox, 20170412.1.0)`

When trying to prune I got couple of messages that some boxes are in use and if I delete the box my environment will get corrupted.

What happens to existing machines if I delete all the boxes?

I tested by creating new machine by using centos/7 - 1708.01.

- Installed `whois` and `vim`
- Created a dummy file in home folder.
- Stopped the machine
- Removed box with `vagrant box remove centos/7 --provider virtualbox  --box-version 1708.01`.
- Started using `vagrant up` and machine started without any issues.

It still had the packages I installed and the file I created.

I did same test with `ubuntu/xenial64`.

- Created a machine using latest box version.
- Installed new packages and touched couple of files.
- stopped machine
- removed latest version of ubuntu/xenial64
- started machine again

I could still see the packages I installed and files were there also.

If deleting boxes doesn't affect existing machine, then why there is message about getting environment corrupted?

My understanding was that after I use a box to create machine vagrant doesn't care if box exist or not as machine is now in virtualbox.

I tried to go through documentation but couldn't find the info I was looking for. 
Could you please explain the whole workflow of vagrant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right;

basically when you run `vagrant up` vagrant is cloning the box to create a new instance VM. Once this VM has been created, it has no link to the clone (original box) so if you remove the box, it does not affect the generated VM.

You will have issue if you need to destroy and recreate the VM.

It works slightly differently if you're using [linked clones VM](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/configuration.html#linked-clones) and in this case, there is stronger dependency with the box.

Comment: Thanks. It means I'll only have issue if I can't download the box and want to recreate the VM. I have used linked clones in virtualbox but never used in vagrant.